# Github shows incorrect timestamp with commits even when system time is fine

Tags: git, github, timestamp

My github account shows that the commits are from a time about 9hours before the actual time of the commit. I checked my system clock and it is working fine.

```
$> date
Wed Jul  6 15:36:53 IST 2016
$> date +%z
+0530
```

How can I fix this issue? Shouldn't git be taking the system time with the commits?

Comment: Are you asking about GitHub displaying not the time saved in commit, or you are asking about Git saving incorrect time in commit you made?

Comment: @PetSerAl : The commit shows an incorrect time. So if I commit something now and push it (assume time now is 10PM) then the commit on github shows I pushed it on the same day at 2PM.

Comment: What if look at your commit locally, does them contain correct date or not?

Comment: @PetSerAl : In a magical turn of events, I see that all my new commits are being timed properly. As for the previous commits where I spotted this anomaly, the timestamps on the commit itself are incorrect (I checked via `git log`). So it looks like my system clock was mistimed and got fixed in my initial attempts to fix this issue. 

PS : I am not sure what does one do in such cases on stackoverflow. Should I remove the question? Or answer saying it was indeed a system clock issue?